# Callback parameters name

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

In this simple node.js code

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err.toString());
    console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log('End of the program');
```

How does the compiler know that `err` will be triggered if there is an error, and `data` will be the data read from the file?

Is it related to the order of the argument? If yes, how can I know how many arguments I can use?

**EDIT** Sorry, did not read properly the documentation.

Comment: a good idea would be to read the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's by the order of the arguments.

And you'd know by the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

> The callback is passed two arguments `(err, data)`, where `data` is the contents of the file.

You might also take a look at [Node style callbacks](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_node_style_callbacks) under the Node.js [Errors](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html) docs.

Comment: Yep, sorry, just saw this one :s

Answer (score 0):

> How does the compiler know that err will be triggered if there is an error, and data will be the data read from the file?

Because the code for `readFile` defines it as such.

> Is it related to the order of the argument?

Yes. Just like any other function call.

> If yes, how can I know how many arguments I can use?

By reading the documentation (or source code) for the function that calls your callback.